# How to find the optimum when using regularization?

Tags: cross-validation, model-evaluation, bias-variance-tradeoff, training-error

Using regularization increases the training error and the validation possibly as well.

How do I find the optimum? Still just the optimum of the bias² and variance, like here:

[image: img1]
Source: https://dziganto.github.io/cross-validation/data%20science/machine%20learning/model%20tuning/python/Model-Tuning-with-Validation-and-Cross-Validation/

How do I know then how strong the regularization should be?

Comment: In the graph, which model do you think is the best? Why?

Comment: If you generated the graph, how? // I like the StatQuest video on using cross validation when you fit a regularized regression in R. Even if you will use other software like Python, the concepts he discusses will apply and have analogous functions.

Comment: @Sycorax I'd say the so-called sweet spot in the middle - I was just wondering whether regularization will shift both errors so the shape does not really change and I can still go for the sweet spot like without using regularization? Or if there happens something else, indeed.

Comment: @Dave StatQuest is the best :) Will check it out!

Answer (score 2):

You normally choose the level of regularization that minimises the validation error.

This means that the validation set, as well as the training set, has influenced your model. So to decide the model performance you need a test set separate from the validation set.

Comment: Thank you, does this mean, in principle, that the validation error is more important?

Comment: No. The test error is more important: it is the best evidence you have of the future error of your predictions, based only on the assumption that the test set is a sample from the same distribution as the future cases.

Comment: But you do not fit the test set, not even to decide the regularization parameter. If you do, it ceases to be an unbiased predictor of future error.

Comment: I'm not fitting the test set? How else would I make use of it?

Comment: A test set is used only for one purpose: to measure the performance of the model you have created.